# UV-Map does not show on bevels

Tags: uv, image, bevel

I am pretty new to blender (2.93.5). It took me pretty long to model a soda can, but finally, I made it.
In the next step, I wanted to map a picture onto the surface of the cans. I already applied a material node and the image shows on the can. But unfortunately, the image does not go around the bevels on top and bottom of the can. What do I do wrong?
Thanks for helping me.
cheers
Jan

[image]

Comment: hello, there must be a problem with your unwrap or your image, please pack your image (File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend (or Pack Resources in Blender 3) and share your file here (upload and copy paste the URL): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/60a47140c1264eb381d276ee3e051e71

Comment: I hope the link works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your problem is bad unwrapping. First select all in *Edit* mode, choose a front view and unwrap again with the *Cylinder Projection* mode:

[image]

Make sure that you've enabled the *Scale to Bounds* option in the *Operator* box:

[image]

You end up with that:

[image]